# VLC telnet interface on Windows

Tags: windows, video-streaming, telnet, vlc

I'm trying to programmatically launch the VLC telnet interface to facilitate some video streaming. My code works correctly on OSX, but on Windows I get an error like:

```
lua error: Error loading script [vlchome]\lua\intf\telnet.luac: ...ckage/win32/../../../share/lua/intf/modules/host.lua:279: attempt to call field 'poll' (a nil value)
```

I've tried this on two different Windows machines, both with VLC up to date, and got the same result on both. Is this a bug, and if so, is there a reasonable alternative (within VLC) that allows me to transcode videos and serve them over a network as VODs?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug since version greater than 2.0.8.
I have the same problem.
Still waiting for patch.

https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/query?summary=~telnet&status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=milestone&col=version&col=owner&col=priority&col=component

Comment: Maybe [https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/10315](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/10315) would be a better link.